# Autostart in .xinitrc

Tags: xorg, autostart, xserver, awesome

I want to run some program at awesomewm startup. I have in my .xinitrc this line:

```
exec awesome
```

It works. Then I added this:

```
exec guake
```

I got errors. So I did this:

```
guake
```

I put each of these lines separately before "exec awesome", after it. It does not work. I tried the same with other programs. The result was the same.
I don't want to rely on awesomewm capabilities to start programs, I know about them. I want to make it in .xintirc.
How to launch a program at awesomewm startup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to run all processes except the last in in the background by adding `&` to them.
So your file should look like

```
guake &
some other program &
exec awesome
```

`exec` replaces the batch you are running, so any `exec`s after the first won't work.

If you don't send the programs into the background, `some other program` would only start when `guake` ends and so on...

Comment: "If you don't send the programs into the background, some other program would only start when guake ends and so on" - so, why my xinitrc started awesomewm when I wrote: guake exec awesome. From your words, awesomewm should not be started, before guake finishes its work.

Comment: It may be that guake returns after sending itdelf into the background. I don't know guake. You were a bit short in your question: "I got errors" - so I had to guess...